# How to get visible cells count from XCUIElementQuery UITesting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am looking at getting the number of visible cells from a `XCUIApplication` `CollectionViews`

This returns the number of items in a `collectionView`

`let count  = XCUIApplication().collectionViews.cells.count`

Comment: Couldn't you check if the cells are hittable?

Comment: Thanks @colinrf , just noticed your comment, already worked around the visible cells. Your approach works BTW ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around a solution, just made an `XCUIApplciation` `extension` to calculate the visible cells:

> **Swift 3.x**

```
extension XCUIApplication {

 func getVisibleCellsCount()-> Int {
     var visibleCount = 0
     var isInitialCellVisible = true

     for i in 0...cells.count {
         let cell = cells.element(boundBy: UInt(i))
         if cell.exists, !cell.isHittable {
             if i == 0 || !isInitialCellVisible {
                 isInitialCellVisible = false
             } else {
                 return visibleCount
             }
         } else {
             isInitialCellVisible = true
             visibleCount += 1
         }
     }
     return visibleCount
 }
}
```